# Shuffle vector elements such that two similar elements coming together at most twice

Tags: matlab, vector, random, constraints, shuffle

For the sake of an example:

I have a vector named vec containing ten 1s and ten 2s. I am trying to randomly arrange it but with one condition that two same values must not come together more than twice.

What I have done till now is generating random indexes of vec using the randperm function and shuffling vec accordingly. This is what I have:

```
vec = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2];
atmost = 2;
indexes = randperm(length(vec));
vec = vec(indexes);

>> vec =
      2  1  1  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  2  1  2  2  2
```

My code randomly arranges elements of vec but does not fulfill the condition of two similar values coming at most two times. How can I do this? Any ideas?

Comment: I would strongly suggest adding tags that will bring your question to the attention of people who have the knowledge to answer it. At least [tag:algorithm] and probably [tag:combinatorics] as well. I would add them for you, but I don't know which of the existing tags you would want to replace.

Answer (score 2):

You can first determine the lengths of the runs of one value, and then fit the other values around them.

In the explanation I'll use values of `a` and `b` in the vector, so as not to confuse the values of the elements of the vector (1 and 2) and the lengths of the runs for each element (1 and 2).

The end goal is to use [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) to construct the shuffled vector. `repelem` takes a vector of the elements to repeat, and a vector of how many times to repeat each element. For example, if we have:

```matlab
v = [b   a   b   a   b   a   b   a   b   a   b   a   b   a   b   a   b]
n = [1   1   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   0]
```

`repelem` will return:

```
shuffled_vec = [b  a  b  a  a  b  a  b  b  a  b  b  a  b  a  b  a  a  b  a]
```

As a first step, I'll generate random values for the counts corresponding to the `a` values. In this example, that would be:

```
a_grouping = [1   2   1   1   1   1   2   1]
```

First, randomly select the number of 2's in the grouping vector. There can be at most `n/2` of them. Then add 1's to make up the desired total.

```
num_total = 10;   % number of a's (and b's)
% There can be 0..num_total/2 groups of two a's in the string.
two_count = randi(num_total/2 + 1) - 1;
% The remainder of the groups of a's have length one.
one_count = num_total - (2*two_count);
% Generate random permutation of two_count 2's and one_count 1's
a_grouping = [repmat(2, 1, two_count), repmat(1, 1, one_count)];
```

This will give us something like:

```
a_grouping = [2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1]
```

Now shuffle:

```
a_grouping = a_grouping(randperm(numel(a_grouping)));
```

With the result:

```
a_grouping = [1   2   1   1   1   1   2   1]
```

Now we need to figure out where the `b` values go. There must be at least one `b` between each run of `a` values (and at most two), and there may be 0, 1 or 2 `b` values at the beginning and end of the string. So we need to generate counts for each of the `x` and `y` values below:

```
all_grouping = [y  1  x  2  x  1  x  1  x  1  x  1  x  2  x  1  y]
```

The `x` values *must* be at least 1, so we'll assign them first. Since the `y` values can be either 0, 1 or 2, we'll leave them set to 0.

```
% Between each grouping of a's, there must be at least one b.
% There can be 0, 1, or 2 b's before and after the a's,
% so make room for them as well.
b_grouping = zeros(1, numel(a_grouping) - 1 + 2);
b_grouping(2:end-1) = 1;   % insert one b between each a group
```

For each of the the remaining counts we need to assign, just select a random slot. If it's not filled yet (i.e. if it's < 2), increment the count, otherwise find a different slot.

```
% Assign location of remaining 2's 
for s = numel(a_grouping):num_total
   unassigned = true;
   while unassigned
      % generate random indices until we find one that's open 
      idx = randi(numel(b_grouping));
      if b_grouping(idx) < 2
         b_grouping(idx) = b_grouping(idx) + 1;
         unassigned = false;
      end
   end
end
```

Now we've got separate counts for the `a`'s and `b`'s:

```
a_grouping = [1   2   1   1   1   1   2   1]
b_grouping = [1   1   1   2   2   1   1   1   0]
```

We'll build the value vector (`v` from the start of the example) and interleave the groupings (the `n` vector).

```
% Interleave the  a and b values
group_values = zeros(1, numel(a_grouping) + numel(b_grouping));
group_values(1:2:end) = 2;
group_values(2:2:end) = 1;
% Interleave the corresponding groupings
all_grouping = zeros(size(group_values));
all_grouping(2:2:end) = a_grouping;
all_grouping(1:2:end) = b_grouping;
```

Finally, `repelem` puts everything together:

```
shuffled_vec = repelem(group_values, all_grouping)
```

The final result is:

```
shuffled_vec =
   1   2   2   1   1   2   1   1   2   2   1   1   2   2   1   1   2   2   1   2
```

Full code:

```matlab
num_total = 10;   % number of a's (and b's)
% There can be 0..num_total/2 groups of two a's in the string.
two_count = randi(num_total/2 + 1) - 1;
% The remainder of the groups of a's have length one.
one_count = num_total - (2*two_count);
% Generate random permutation of two_count 2's and one_count 1's
a_grouping = [repmat(2, 1, two_count), repmat(1, 1, one_count)];
a_grouping = a_grouping(randperm(numel(a_grouping)));
% disp(a_grouping)

% Between each grouping of a's, there must be at least one b.
% There can be 0, 1, or 2 b's before and after the a's,
% so make room for them as well.
b_grouping = zeros(1, numel(a_grouping) - 1 + 2);
b_grouping(2:end-1) = 1;   % insert one b between each a group
% Assign location of remaining 2's 
for s = numel(a_grouping):num_total
   unassigned = true;
   while unassigned
      % generate random indices until we find one that's open 
      idx = randi(numel(b_grouping));
      if b_grouping(idx) < 2
         b_grouping(idx) = b_grouping(idx) + 1;
         unassigned = false;
      end
   end
end

% Interleave the  a and b values
group_values = zeros(1, numel(a_grouping) + numel(b_grouping));
group_values(1:2:end) = 2;
group_values(2:2:end) = 1;
% Interleave the corresponding groupings
all_grouping = zeros(size(group_values));
all_grouping(2:2:end) = a_grouping;
all_grouping(1:2:end) = b_grouping;

shuffled_vec = repelem(group_values, all_grouping)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should generate fairly random non-consecutive vectors. Whether it covers all possibilities uniformly, I'm not sure.

```
out=[];
for i=1:10
    if randi(2)==1
        out=[out,1,2];
    else
        out=[out,2,1];
    end
end
disp(out)
```

Example results

```
1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,
2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,
1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,
2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,
2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,
2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,
1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,
2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,
1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,
1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,
```